# Why does assignment to -CLLocationManager.delegate sometimes copy its value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, delegates, cllocationmanager

I have a unit test that makes sure that the object assigned to a CLLocationManager is a specific object:

```
    CLLocationManager *loc = weakColl.lm;
    XCTAssertTrue(
        loc.delegate == (id)weakColl,
        @"The collection should be the location manager delegate"
    );
```

However, this test is failing on some devices (CDMA iPhone 6/iOS 8). I put some `NSLog()` calls in the code that does the assignment to try to figure out what's happening:

```
    id lm = [CLLocationManager new];
    [lm setDelegate:(id)self];
    NSLog(@"SELF:      %p", self);
    NSLog(@"Delegate:  %p", [lm delegate]);
```

The address is the same on most platforms, but on the failing devices, it's not:

```
SELF:      0x15647af0
Delegate:  0x155589a0
```

What the hell? I had a look at the header file; it's supposed to be an `assign` property:

```
@property(assign, nonatomic) id<CLLocationManagerDelegate> delegate;
```

So I don't understand. Why on earth would the references be different in this case?

Comment: I would say to try replacing `assign` with `weak` and to use `isEqual:` rather than  `==`

Comment: @LouisTur I have no control over the definition of CLLocationManager's properties. And the point is to make sure the proper *object* is assigned, not that it's equivalent.

Comment: ah apologies, misread the question